# dateFormat in react date picker doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, format, react-datepicker

i wish to get the date in the format `yyyy/MM/dd`
but it doesn't seem to work when i `console.log` the value

```
<DatePicker dateFormat='dd/MM/yyyy' selected={startDate} onChange={(date)=>{
          setStartDate(date)
          console.log(startDate)
        }}/>
```

i get the following format

```
Fri Dec 31 2021 18:10:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

i will want in the form `yyyy-mm-dd` to finally insert the date into a sql table

i can see that format in the date-picker component but when console.log then it shows a different format or it will be useful even if it possible to get the value shown directly like `e.target.value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dateFormat prop controls how the date is displayed in the input field next to the date picker.

The actual value of the date picker will still be a Date object.

There are various ways of getting only the date (in a specific format) form this date.

I would suggest applying one of these for example (.toLocaleDateString()) before you send it to your api/server.

Keep in mind that .toLocaleDateString() also allows you to pass the locales, and or any options like a timezone, or a format which you might want to specify. See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) for more examples.

Comment: as you said it did always store as a date object, only the visual date was changed using dateFormat. However i used the toLocaleDateString() and formatted it to my needs